# How to feed predefined k-folds in GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I would like to use GridSearchCV for parameter tuning and evaluation over 10 predefined selected folds of data that I have (as list of lists of data indices).

Does anyone know how to feed GridSearchCV in scikit with 10 lists of predefined test folds?

`splits=[ [0,10,9,1,2,..] ,[3,5,7,..],[23,4,34,..]]
 #len(split)=10`

`greed_search = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid=parameters, cv=splits,scoring=scoring, refit=score, error_score=0, n_jobs=n_jobs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to preprocess your folds a little bit like this:

```
new_splits = []

for i in range(len(splits)):
    train = [j for i in splits[:i] + splits[i + 1:] for j in i]
    test = splits[i]
    new_splits.append([train, test])
```

To get not only test parts in iterable, but also train part as well